# NetSuite add sublist function

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a customer that wants to distinguish between drop ship addresses and direct custom addresses on their NetSuite resellers.

To do this, I have added a checkbox field on the address form and I am creating two new sublists on the address tab in NetSuite, which will separate the addresses sublists into two categories.

From my understanding, I cannot do a saved search on NetSuite to create these two sublists, so I am creating a suite script (UserEvent BeforeLoad)

I am now trying to load the addresses into the sublists; how can I load the addresses by record id rather than creating new lines? Do I need to specify the sublist type as an address and then add the record by id on the list? I'm unsure.

I have attached my code of how I created the suite scripts.

```
       resellerForm.addSublist({
            id: RESELLER_FIELDS.DIRECTSHIP_ADDRESS_SUBLIST,
            type: serverWidget.SublistType.INLINEEDITOR,
            label: 'Direct Ship Addresses',
            tab: "address"
        });

        resellerForm.addSublist({
            id: RESELLER_FIELDS.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_SUBLIST,
            type: serverWidget.SublistType.INLINEEDITOR,
            label: 'Customer Addresses',
            tab: "address"
        });
        
        ....
        
        var lineCount = 0;
            directShip.each(function (result) {
                reseller.insertLine({
                    sublistId: RESELLER_FIELDS.DIRECTSHIP_ADDRESS_SUBLIST,
                    ignoreRecalc: true,
                    line: lineCount++
                });
                address = record.load({id: record.id, type: result.recordType})
                // TODO: do something with address to put it in sublist
                reseller.commitLine({sublistId: RESELLER_FIELDS.DIRECTSHIP_ADDRESS_SUBLIST})
                return true
            })
```

Thank you